# I am new in using ArrayLists. Array Out of Bounds, Array seems to be empty, but have been adding Strings to it already

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

My instructor suggested to use ArrayList, and this is my first time using one. I keep getting ang error of ArrayList OutofBounds. I get teh idea that is empty, but i have been adding to the ArrayList. Maybe it couldn't add, and i'm stuck. T^T

```
for(; pizza.i<3;pizza.i++){
        if(jComboBox5.getSelectedIndex()==pizza.i){
            pizza = new Pepperoni(pizza);
            pizza.count();
            //pizza.toppings.add(""+i+" Pepperoni");
            //pizza.toppingctr++;
            System.out.println(pizza.i+"Pepperoni"+(++pizza.toppingctr));

        }
        if(jComboBox6.getSelectedIndex()==pizza.i){
            pizza = new Mushroom(pizza);
            pizza.count();

            System.out.println(pizza.i+"Mu"+(++pizza.toppingctr));
        } ........
}for(int i=0; i<pizza.toppingctr;i++){
        System.out.println(pizza.toppings.get(i));
    }
```

The System.out.println and the i, works how it should be working. I think the problem is on pizza.count (found in Pepperoni, Mushroom, and etc) where i actually add Strings to my ArrayList.

```
public int count(){
        pizza.toppings.add(""+pizza.i+" Pepperoni");
        return (pizza.toppingctr+1);
    }
```

Pepperoni (and others) extends to PizzaDecorator, and PizzaDecorator extends to Pizza, where the arraylist is initialized.

```
ArrayList<String> toppings =new ArrayList<String>();
```

update:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"     java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
at pizzabasedresto.PizzaPanel.jButton1ActionPerformed(PizzaPanel.java:832)
at pizzabasedresto.PizzaPanel.access$2300(PizzaPanel.java:18)
at pizzabasedresto.PizzaPanel$24.actionPerformed(PizzaPanel.java:422)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:
```

The stack trace doesn't show what line it is, but when i remove the

```
for(int i=0; i<pizza.toppingctr;i++){
        System.out.println(pizza.toppings.get(i));
    }
```

the exception is gone. so the statement who throws exception is that

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace (formatted as code) and identify the statement in your code that is throwing the exception.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the COMPLETE stack trace (formatted as code).  Then find the statement in your code that is mentioned in the stack trace (by line number) and tell us which statement that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, and that's supposed to solve the problem. If you use an ArrayList you should check its documentation. When you supposed to go through a simple array you use "nameOfArray.length", right? Well, the ArrayList has the method ".size()" which bascialy has the same use.
So your loop would be better this way :

```
for(int i=0; i<pizza.toppings.size();i++){
    System.out.println(pizza.toppings.get(i));
}
```

This way you're sure you'll never get out of your array's length.

Now of course there is still a problem with your value. And it's hard to tell where it is for two reasons :

1. We miss the important parts of your code (such as the constructor)
2. Because the pizza.toppingctr is public and shouldn't be.

You'd better increment it in your count() method and have it private. 
And in fact, if you use the ".size()" method, you shouldn't need it at all.